# JMS replyTo, create Temporary Queue in different JMS provider where request is sent

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, weblogic, message-queue, messaging

With JMS, there is a concept of Temporary Queue. It is a queue, which exists only in the particular JMS connection. It is created during transaction by the client, and is destroyed when the connection is closed. Temporary Queue may be used as a JMS replyTo address per se JMS API. It is convenient way to implement request-reply pattern with JMS.

But is it possible to open JMS connections to **two distinct** JMS servers in **different WebLogic domains**, create Temporary Queue in other JMS server and use it as a replyTo address in the message sent to another JMS server? Also, JMS servers in both WebLogic domains are clustered (distributed destinations) if that matters.

[image]

1. For the transaction, Service 1 creates Temporary Queue in it's JMS provider
2. Service 1 sends message to another JMS provider in different domain. Message contains the Temporary Queue as replyTo address. Service 1 blocks until reply message arrives at the Temporary Qeueue.
3. Service 2 MDB handles the incoming request message
4. Service 2 sends reply message to Service 1's Temporary Qeueue.
5. Service 1 handles the incoming reply message.

There will be multiple instances of both services. Also, message may be routed even further to another domains from Service 2 before being returned to Service 1. The Temporary Queue replyTo address must endure all the "hops" in the route. Is this possible with pure Java EE?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do here isn't possible simply by using the `JMSReplyTo` message header because the JMS specification does not define any link between a `Destination` and a physical location. A `Destination` is essentially just a reference to an implementation-specific name where the message will be sent. That said, you could include additional properties in the message with the details required to connect to the proper remote server (e.g. name of the connection factory and IP/port for the JNDI lookup).